# The composition of $\Delta_0$ fn's $f, g: HF\to HF$ is not necessarily $\Delta_0$?

Tags: set-theory, computability

I am trying to solve the following exercise in Ken Kunen's book *The Foundations of Mathematics*
[image]

The hint vaguely makes sense at the high level but I am unable to follow the proof skeleton. (I am interested in particular in a proof following the given proof skeleton hint, because I am the TA for a class using this text and I want to know if the students will be able to produce a correct proof following the hint; I'm not just interested in a correct proof of the theorem.)

I first established that the basic operators involving pairing and projection of ordered pairs can all be added harmlessly to a $\Delta_0$ formula without affecting it.

Let $f : HF\to HF$ be a function whose graph is $\Delta_1$. Then by
definition there is a $\Delta_0$ formula $\varphi$ such that
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=y\iff \exists z. \varphi(x,y,z)
\end{equation}
Let $x$ be any $HF$ set. Denote by $n_x$ the least natural number $n$ such
that $\exists y,z\in R(n),\varphi(x,y,z)$. Denote by $R_x$ the
disjoint sum of all $R(n)$ for $n\leq n_x$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
R_x = \coprod_{n\leq n_x}R(n) = \left\{ \left\langle n,R(n)
  \right\rangle \mid n\leq n_x\right\}
\end{equation}
Denote by $h: HF\to HF$ the function which sends $x$ to $\left\langle
  x,R_x \right\rangle$. We will prove $h$ is $\Delta_0$.

First, by (6.) of Example II.17.5, $\left\langle x,y \right\rangle=z$
is logically equivalent to a $\Delta_0$ sentence, which Kunen calls
$\operatorname{op}(x,y,z)$. Note also that ``$z$ is an ordered pair'',
$\exists b\in z,\exists x,y\in p.p=\left\langle x,y \right\rangle$ is
then $\Delta_0$ in $z$. This is pointed out in (14.) of Lemma
II.17.9. I call this $\operatorname{op}(z)$ and use the number of
arguments to distinguish them. Note that if $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are the
projection operators onto the first and second argument of an ordered
pair (and return the empty set if the argument is not an ordered pair)
then $\operatorname{op}(z)\land P(x_{1},\dots, x_k,\pi_1(z))$ is logically
equivalent to
$\exists b\in z,\exists x,y\in b, \operatorname{op}(x,y,z)\land P(x_1,\dots,x_k,x)$
which is $\Delta_0$ in the free variable $z$, so I can use the
projection operators freely in a $\Delta_0$ sentence.

By (10.) of Lemma II.17.9, the sentence ``$n$ is a natural number'' is
$\Delta_0$. By abuse of notation, I write $n\in \omega$; but be
careful to recall that $\omega$ does not denote a term in $HF$.
Lastly observe that $\exists ! a\in b. P(x_1,\dots, x_k,a)$ is
logically equivalent to the  $\Delta_0$ sentence $\exists a\in
b.P(x_1,\dots, x_k,a) \land \forall a,a'\in
b. P(x_1,\dots,x_k,a')\land P(x_1,\dots, x_k,a)\implies a=a'$.

So define $h$ by $\psi(x,t) = \operatorname{op}(t)\land \pi_1(t)=x \land
\pi_2(t)=R_x$.  We will show that the relation $s=R_x$ is $\Delta_0$
in $s$ and $x$; from here it is clear that $\psi$ is a $\Delta_0$
definition of $h$.

Define
\begin{align}
  \gamma(x,s):= & \forall p\in s. \operatorname{op}(p)\land \pi_1(p)\in \omega \land
                  \pi_2(p)=R(\pi_1(p))\\
                &\textrm{"s is a set of ordered pairs} \\
                &\textrm{of the form } (n,R(n)) \textrm{ where } n\in \omega"\\
                & \forall p\in s. \forall n'\in \pi_1(p)\exists p'\in
                  s.\pi_1(p')=n'\\
                &\textrm{"if }(n,R(n))\in s,\textrm{ so is
                  }(n',R(n'))\textrm{ for }n'<n" \\
                & \exists ! q\in s.\exists y,z\in \pi_2(q).\varphi(x,y,z)\\
                &\textrm{"in a unique pair }(n,R(n))\textrm{ witnesses }y,z\textrm{ to
    }\varphi \textrm{ exist in }R(n)"\\
\end{align}
However this is not quite right. For this to be correct I would have to establish that the relation
$a=R(n)$ is $\Delta_0$, which is equivalent to saying that the graph
of the function $n\mapsto R(n)$ is $\Delta_0$. But we don't have that, per se. What we have, given in a previous lemma, is that the graph of $n\mapsto \coprod_{m<n}R(m)$ is $\Delta_0$. This  means somehow I need to get hold of the quantity $n_x+1$; but I don't know how to "construct" it in a $\Delta_0$ way from $n_x$ or from $R_x$. I am a bit lost in the face of the unique handicap that I am unable to freely introduce function symbols representing functional relations in virtue of the fact stated in the problem.

Comment: Is being $\Delta_0$ or $\Delta_1$ means being $\Delta_0$ or $\Delta_1$ over $V$, or $\mathrm{HF}$?

Comment: If you meant the former, then we may use the following formulation: for $n>1$, $a=R(n)$ if there is $f\in \mathrm{HF}$ such that $f:a\to n$, $f=\operatorname{rank}\upharpoonright a$, and if $x,y\in a$ and $f(y)<n-1$ then $x\cup\{y\}\in a$.

Comment: Hi Hanul; thank you. I meant over $HF$, here, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I will think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key ideas are

1. Even if we do not know $R(n)=x$ is $\Delta_0$, $R_x$ contains sufficient information to define itself.
2. $V_\omega$ is the closure of $\{\varnothing\}$ under the operation $x,y\mapsto x\cup\{y\}$.

---

Let us consider the conjunction of the following formulas:

- $s$ is a function such that $\operatorname{dom} s$ is an ordinal (so $V$ thinks  $\operatorname{dom} s\in\omega$) ,
- $s(0)=0$,
- For $n\in\operatorname{dom}s$ such that $n+1\in\operatorname{dom}s$, if $x,y\in s(n)$ then $x\cup\{y\}\in s(n+1)$.
- For $m=\bigcup\operatorname{dom}s$, there are $y,z\in s(m)$ such that $\phi(x,y,z)$, and
- If $k<m$, then no $y,z\in s(k)$ satisfy $\phi(x,y,z)$.

It is easy to see that the listed formulas are all $\Delta_0$

To prove $s=R_x$, it suffices to prove that $s(n)=R(n)$ for each $n\in\operatorname{dom}s$. By induction, assume that $s(n)=R(n)$. For each $a\in R(n+1)$, we have
$a = \bigcup\{\{b\}\mid b\in a\}$, and each $b\in a$ is an element of $R(n)$. Hence we can prove $a\in s(n+1)$ by induction on the size of $a$.